# How to do Animation Anchoring in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

There is an animation feature that exists in AngularJS 1.4 that is called
[Animation Anchoring](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate#animation-anchoring-via-ng-animate-ref-).

When routing to a new route, it allows to mark an element in the source and destination page with the attribute `ng-animate-ref`, and performs a computed animation between the two by creating a cloned node during the transition.

[See demo](https://docs.angularjs.org/examples/example-anchoringExample/index.html#!/)

Is it possible to do something similar in Angular 2+ ?

Examples I found in the documentation only deals with animation to a specific component or dom element, but nothing like this cloning feature.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up creating it myself:

https://github.com/foxx9/ngx-animate-ref

Comment: Why answer your own question? This takes away opportunity for others to answer. Instead try to edit your question and provide an possible solution there.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30983873)